# How does NetworkManager get external devices?

Tags: networkmanager

Using Debian 12.2 with KDE Plasma 5.27.5

Where does `nmcli device` acquire the information about the external devices `docker0`, `virbr0` ?

```
# nmcli device console output
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
eno1     ethernet  connected               Wired_eno1
lo       loopback  connected (externally)  lo
docker0  bridge    connected (externally)  docker0
virbr0   bridge    connected (externally)  virbr0
enp5s0   ethernet  unavailable             --
```

For completeness, the content of ` is:

```bash
cat `/etc/network/interfaces

# console output
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


ls -l /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

# console output
-rw------- 1 root root 322 Nov 15 09:15 Forti_VPN
-rw------- 1 root root 210 Nov 14 21:48 Wired_eno1
```

Reading [Get started with NetworkManager on Linux](https://opensource.com/article/22/4/networkmanager-linux). I learn that NetworkManager uses the information from D-Bus to initialize each NIC

> The udev daemon creates an entry for each network interface card (NIC) installed in the system in the network rules file. D-Bus signals the presence of a new network device—wired or wireless—to NetworkManager. NetworkManager then listens to the traffic on the D-Bus and responds by creating a configuration for this new device. Such a configuration is, by default, stored only in RAM and is not permanent. It must be created every time the computer is booted.

But where does `udev` get the info about the network devices, physical like `eno1`, `enp5s0` or virtual like `docker0`, `virbr0` ?

For the sake of learning, what are the manual steps or commands that I could run to query `udev` for info about the network devices discovered by NetworkManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel generates an *udev event* for the addition, change or removal of *any device*, including network devices. Since `udev` monitors these events, it will become aware of all network devices as soon as the applicable driver detects the hardware.

To query udev for network devices, you cannot use `udevadm info -q all -n <device node>`, because network devices don't have device nodes. But you *can* query them by using the sysfs path:

```
udevadm info -q all -p /sys/class/net/<interface name>
```

or

```
udevadm info -q all -a -p /sys/class/net/<interface name>
```

The former command will tell you all the possible names for the network interface using the new [Predictable Network Interface Names scheme](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/), with the various `ID_NET_NAME_*` environment variables.

The latter command will list all udev attributes for the network interface device and all its parents (if applicable), which may be useful if you need to write a custom udev rule, e.g. to assign a name for a network interface based on some unusual attribute.